# Best practice for exiting batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

For a batch file I want to check for different conditions and have a help message

Which one is the best practice for exiting the batch file after displaying the message?

```
if "%1"=="/?"(
  echo "help message"
  exit /b 0
)
[more code]
```

or

```
if "%1"=="/?"(
  echo "help message"
  goto :EOF
)
[more code]
:EOF
```

The first one seems better for my untrained eyes but a lot of the examples online use the `GOTO` tag method

What is the SO community's opinion on this?

Comment: In your searches,  have you come across [this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/exit.php)?

Comment: They do almost the exact same thing; except `exit /b` can also set the errorlevel variable, which you may need to do occasionally. Other than that, it's simply personal preference.

Comment: You don't need to define label `:EOF` (if Command Extensions are enabled). However, if you specify it, `GOTO EOF` and `GOTO :EOF` behave differently: while the former jumps to the label, the latter jumps to the very end. (I'm using Win7 x64.)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Personally I use `exit`.

> - The normal `exit` command simply terminates the current script, and the parent (for example if you were running a script from command line, or calling it from another batch file)
> - `exit /b` is used to terminate the current script, but leaves the parent window/script/calling label open.
> - With exit, you can also add an error level of the exit. For example, `exit /b 1` would produce an `%errorlevel%` of 1. Example:

```
@echo off
call :getError     rem Calling the :getError label
echo Errorlevel: %errorlevel%     rem Echoing the errorlevel returned by :getError
 pause

:getError
exit /b 1    rem exiting the call and setting the %errorlevel% to 1
```

Would print:

```
Errorlevel: 1
press any key to continue...
```

Setting error levels with this method can be useful when creating batch scripts that may have things that fail. You could create separate `:labels` for different errors, and have each return a unique error level.

> - `goto :eof` ends the current script (call) but not the parent file, (similarly to `exit /b`)
> - Unlike exit, in which you can set an exiting errorlevel, `goto :eof` automatically sets the errorlevel to the currently set level, making it more difficult to identify problems.

The two can also be used in unison in the same batch file:

```
@echo off
call :getError
echo %errorlevel%
pause
goto :eof

:getError 
exit /b 2
```

Another method of exiting a batch script would be to use `cmd /k` When used in a stand-alone batch file, `cmd /k` will return you to regular command prompt.

All in all i would recommend using `exit` just because you can set an errorlevel, but, it's really up to you.

Answer (score 6):

There is no functional or performance difference between GOTO :EOF vs EXIT /B, except that EXIT /B allows you to specify the returned ERRORLEVEL, and GOTO :EOF does not.

Obviously if you want to specify the ERRORLEVEL when you return, then EXIT /B is preferred.

If you don't care about the return code, or you know that the ERRORLEVEL is already set to the correct value, then it makes no difference - it becomes strictly a matter of preference / coding style.