# Azure-Pipelines - Script that requires Ctrl+C or Typing 'y' to end

Tags: windows, command-line, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure-Pipelines for my CI Pipeline running on windows-2019. One of my cmd scripts generates output report files and continues to run until either Ctrl+C is pressed, or 'y' is typed. How is this done? If I add another script after this one as 'y', it will never reach because the previous command will never terminate.

In the meantime, I added the "timeoutInMinutes" param to the script so it timeouts in a minute, but this still causes a task error which is not ideal.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can end the first script once it's complete? (It takes about 5 seconds to complete the necessary task)

Comment: Why not use exit command in your script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574365/best-practice-for-exiting-batch-file?

Comment: Any update to your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. it is impossible to enter a user input during Azure Pipeline.

You must edit your script to not finish and wait for user input.