# Windows batch script failed condition exit error message

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to convert one of my `bash(.sh)` script into windows `batch(.bat)` script.

I am dealing with windows batch scripting for the first time. Got all the help from various SO threads and able to achieve what I needed except one, the following.

I need to exit on a condition where if a directory does not exist, exit the script. I took help from this thread - [Best practice for exiting batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574365/best-practice-for-exiting-batch-file)

Here is what I am came up with:

```
@echo off

set BACKUP_PARENT_DIR=C:\some\path\on\machine

if not exist %BACKUP_PARENT_DIR% (echo "Error Occurred..." exit /b 1) else (echo "All Good...")

echo "More Statements..."
```

`else` block/condition works fine but I get this as output of `if` condition:

```
"Error Occurred..." exit /b 1
"More Statements..."
```

Also it DOES NOT exit. It continues to run further.

What I want the output to look like is:

```
"Error Occurred..."
```

**Question:** What should I do in order to exit completely from the script execution and get rid of `exit /b 1` from the failed condition of the 'if' block in the output printed on the command prompt?

Comment: to get rid of it, just delete it. If you want to execute two commands (`echo ...` and `exit`, put a `&` between: `echo Error Occurred... & exit /b 1`

Comment: Btw: Windows' `echo` doesn't use quotes for the argument, so remove them (except you want them to be in the output)

Comment: Apologies. I updated my question while you were answering. The execution does not exit. that is the additional issues I am having.

Comment: `exit /b` exits the batchfile, but not the cmd session. `exit` without `/b` closes both the script and the session.

Comment: Ahh Nice...!! `echo Error Occurred... & exit` is what I was looking for. Thanks a ton my friend. Could you please put it as answer so that I can accept that? So that others can get to the answer directly if need be.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo "Error Occurred..." exit /b 1` echoes the literal string
`"Error Occurred..." exit /b 1` instead of echoing just `Error Occurrred...` and actually exiting the script.

To execute two commands in the same line, use `&`, `&&` or `||`.

`&` means "and then execute ..."
`&&` means "if successful, then execute ..."
`||` means "if unsuccessful, then execute ..."

Compare the output of the following four lines (Also try with an existing file):

```
dir nonexistent.file & echo finished
dir nonexistent.file && echo found it
dir nonexistent.file || echo no such file
dir nonexistent.file && echo found it || echo no such file
```

Also (unlike many other languages), batch's `echo` doesn't use quotes around the argument. They will just be part of the echoed string.